# Creating a python wrapper for an API using classes

Tags: python, json, api, wrapper

I am trying to make a Python Wrapper for an API. I have been able to create scripts that work fine but don't use classes. I want to make a real wrapper of that API using classes. I am new to OOP in Python.

Following was my attempt but I am stuck at how to convert it to an OO type.

```
import urllib2
from urllib import urlencode
import json

class apiclient:
    def __init__(self,
                request_url,
                hmh_api_key,
                client_id,
                grant_type="password",
                username="username",
                password="password"):

        values = {
                "client_id": client_id,
                "grant_type": grant_type,
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            }

        data = urlencode(values)

        req = urllib2.Request(request_url, data)
        req.add_header("Api-Key", api_key)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

        response_header = response.info().dict
        response_body = response.read()
        json_acceptable_string = response_body.replace("'", "\"")
        response_body_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)

        return response_body_dict ## this is the response

if __name__ == "__main__":

    API_KEY = "75b5cc58a5cdc0a583f91301cefedf0c"
    CLIENT_ID = "ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6.hmhco.com"
    REQUEST_URL = "http://some.url"

    client = apiclient(request_url=REQUEST_URL,
                        api_key=API_KEY,
                        client_id=CLIENT_ID)

    print client
```

Without classes, I get the response JSON as `response_body_dict` but with classes I get `TypeError: __init__() should return None`. How should I start designing my program.
I have shown only a part of the whole program, there are a lot many similar scripts that send requests to URLs and get JSON responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return something from `__init__` function.

**EDIT:**

If you need that value you should use the response_body_dict as a class member and get him from other method:

```
import urllib2
from urllib import urlencode
import json

class apiclient:
    def __init__(self,
                request_url,
                api_key,
                client_id,
                grant_type="password",
                username="username",
                password="password"):

        values = {
                "client_id": client_id,
                "grant_type": grant_type,
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            }

        data = urlencode(values)

        req = urllib2.Request(request_url, data)
        req.add_header("Api-Key", api_key)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

        response_header = response.info().dict
        response_body = response.read()
        json_acceptable_string = response_body.replace("'", "\"")
        self.response_body_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)

    def get_response_body(self):
        return self.response_body_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":

    API_KEY = "75b5cc58a5cdc0a583f91301cefedf0c"
    CLIENT_ID = "ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6.hmhco.com"
    REQUEST_URL = "http://some.url"

    client = apiclient(request_url=REQUEST_URL,
                        api_key=API_KEY,
                        client_id=CLIENT_ID)
    response = client.get_response_body()

    print client
```

Comment: Then how should I rewrite it so that I am able to input whatever keys I have specified and get the response JSON as it contains another key that  have to use in other APIs?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey , I edited my answer to suite for the solution you need.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried another thing where I actually specify each key as `self.client_id` etc in `__init__`. and do all other work in a separate function. I guess that is same as what you did??

Comment: I find yours a better way of doin that. Thanks!

Comment: @AnimeshPandey , If you will need to use them in some other methods than they should be class members. if you use them only locally than they should not be class members.